# Different effect of "height" arg in \vrule

Tags: tex-core, rules, dimensions

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}


\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\fboxsep0pt
\fboxrule1pt
\textcolor{red}{\vrule width 1pt height 1pt}\\% I get a vrule with a height of 1pt as I expect.
\fbox{\parbox{1in}{aa\\AA}}%
\textcolor{red}{\vrule width 1pt height 1pt}% What I want is a vrule with a height of 1pt, so that it aligns with the bottom line of `\fbox` How can I get such a line by \vrule?
\fbox{\parbox{1in}{aa\\AA}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you want consistent behaviour you should use latex commands, the latex command `\rule` would not have the implicit behaviour that you are seeing. If you use TeX primitives then you have to expect to get what you get.

Comment: put xxxx after your last fbox so that you see the baseline, you will see marked red rule does have _height_ 1pt above the baseline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working of `\vrule` is context dependent. If you don't specify a `height`, then the rule will be as high as the enclosing box.<sup>1</sup> If `width` is not specified, it defaults to 0.4pt. *The same* will happen for `depth`, which seems the factor you're not aware of.

Examples (in plain TeX):

```
\hbox{\vrule a}

\hbox{\vrule b}

\hbox{\vrule Xy}
\bye
```

In the last example, you see that also the depth is adjusted to match the enclosing box depth.

If your box happens to have zero height, that will be used for the `\vrule`, so it will be invisible (but it will contribute its width).

Note that the box might be “implicit”: if you use `\vrule` in the middle of a paragraph, its height and depth will default to those of the `\hbox` built during paragraph making in which the `\vrule` will eventually be typeset in.

[image]

If you want *specific* height or depth, you *must* tell TeX with the suitable `height` or `depth` parameter.

What's happening in your example? Here is a picture:

[image]

The rule is indeed 1pt high, but it is as deep as the enclosing box, which happens to contain a `\parbox` which is centered around the baseline (take the formula axis height). A simpler picture:

```
\hbox{\vrule height 1pt Xy}
```

[image]

You can see that the height (the extent above the base line) is 1pt, but the depth is that of the enclosing box.

###### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> Since `\vrule` is a horizontal command, the enclosing box will necessarily be an `\hbox` (either explicit like in the shown example, or constructed during paragraph building).

#### Your aim

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\fparboxwithruleinfront}[4][.]{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\rule{1pt}{#2}}%
  \raisebox{\depth}{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}\fbox{\parbox{#3}{#4}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\fparboxwithruleinfront[red]{1pt}{1in}{aa\\AA}

\bigskip

\fparboxwithruleinfront{4pt}{1in}{aa\\AA}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I modified my code, specific `height` is given(`1pt`) for the sencond `\vrule`, but does not get a vrule with a height of 1pt either. Why and how to achieve it? And why is `\textcolorbox` not an explicit for `\vrule`?

Comment: @lyl It's the depth that kicks in. I added the explanation. Since I can't understand what you're after, in particular as to *where* you expect the rule to appear with respect to the context, it's difficult to say more.

Comment: @lyl it's a bit antisocial to change the question after it has been answered, but you do get a rule of height 1pt, but as you did not specify depth 0pt it picks up the depth of the surrounding box as egreg explains

Comment: I want the vrule is at the bottom of `\fbox` with a height of 1pt so that it is align with the bottom line of `\fbox`

Comment: @lyl And what about the position of the `\fbox` with respect to the baseline?

Comment: `\fbox` on the baseline? I added a picture to illustrate my intention.

Comment: @lyl I added code to that extent

Comment: Thank you @egreg so much!!